# A Docker container (jellyfin) that I'm trying to set up just won't start - no logs, no error messages

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, debian, jellyfin

I'm a Docker newbie - first time I've ever used it. I thought an easy way to get a first taste would be to use the Docker container option to install [Jellyfin](https://jellyfin.org/) on a Raspberry Pi (Docker install instructions are [here](https://jellyfin.org/docs/general/installation/container)).

Except it isn't working.  I installed the docker container on a Raspberry Pi by running `docker pull jellyfin/jellyfin`.

Then I ran

```
docker run -it -u {uid}:{gid} --name jellyfin --net=host --volume {HOMEDIR}/jellyfin-config:/config --volume {HOMEDIR}/jellyfin-cache:/cache --mount type=bind,source={HOMEDIR}/Music,target=/media jellyfin/jellyfin
```

(I have redacted my actual uid and gid and the home directory).

and several variations.  When I do this, I get this output from `docker container list -all`:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED         STATUS                       PORTS     NAMES
020748c27b2d   jellyfin/jellyfin   "/jellyfin/jellyfin"   3 seconds ago   Exited (132) 2 seconds ago             jellyfin
```

I tried to enter the container using `--entrypoint=/bin/bash`.  When I get into the container and type `jellyfin/jellyfin`, I get a single word message `Aborted`.

Running `docker logs` for the container gets me no output at all.  Running docker with the `-it` option, as above, also gets no output.

The user that I am on the system has write access to `jellyfin-config`, `jellyfin-cache`, and `Music`.  When I run `id` inside the container, it reports the same user id and group id as my system user.  When I run `whoami`, however, it says `cannot find name for user xxx`.  When I run `touch test` inside `/cache` when running bash inside the container, I get an error that setting times is not permitted, but the file is written.

I'm not sure what is going on. I thought this might be a bug and have also posted to Jellyfin's issues, but no response there.  Given that I am a Docker newbie, am I just using Docker wrong?  How does one debug an error like this anyway?